# How to change primary key values of custom table in SAP ABAP?

Tags: abap

I want to change primary key values in custom table, when we have multiple primary keys?

In SM30 we can edit the non-primary key values, but in my program I required primary key to be edit. 4 Primary key fields are there.

Normally in SM30 undo button works for non saved data.

Comment: Your question is unclear, please edit it according to these [instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: usually, editing a key field in a table isn't an edit, but a delete and insert. Most programs will update the row identified by the table key, but if you change the table key, that update won't work anymore. There are obviously ways to allow this behavior (most importantly, storing the original key values somewhere to use them in the update) from a purely technical point of view, but from what I've seen in SAP standard transactions, they are not prepared for that.

Comment: There may be some answers in the same question posted in [SCN](https://answers.sap.com/questions/12706715/how-to-change-primary-key-values-in-custom-table-w.html) (currently one)

Answer (score 0):

If understood your question, you want to change an record in SM30. Just copy the record to a new entry and change the primary key field information and later delete the record which is not required.